# Solve first order system of linear differential equations with general forcing

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, dynamical-systems

I have a system of differential equations. $x$ is a vector, $[A]$ is a matrix and $f(t)$ is a time dependent vector.

$$\frac{dx}{dt} = [A]x + f(t)$$

I know the solution to this is:

$$x = e^{[A]t} x_0 + e^{[A]t} \int_{t_0}^t e^{-[A]r}f(r) dr$$

Where $e^{[A]t}$ is the matrix exponential of $[A]t$. How to I physically compute the integral sign though (either numerically or analytically)? For simplicity say: [A] = [1 2; 3 4], x0 = [0, 0], t0 = 0. f(t) = [t ,t^2]

Comment: You have two equal signs It should be $x'=Ax+f$ Your example for $A$ should also be a matrix not a vector.

Comment: Thanks sorry that was a typo. Fixed it now.